# Tapestry - update UI based on a backend event

Tags: java, tapestry

I am using Tapestry 4.1. I have a process running in the background. Once the process completes, I want to refresh a text in my UI. I am new to tapestry. It would be helpful if somebody can point out tapestry components I can use for this purpose.

Comment: for t5 answer, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026162/refreshing-a-tapestry-zone-on-a-regular-basis

Answer (score 0):

just like any web application, you will need to set up some kind of polling mechanism from your browser to your server (ie an ajax request on a timer).

i can't remember how i used to script ajax requests to event listeners in tapestry 4.1 but i do remember doing it.

i could tell you how to do it with tapestry 5 however.